# is it possible to take a google static map api and convert it to a jpg

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd

is it possible to take a google static map api and convert it to a jpg, maybe using GD or Image Magick?

Comment: Another question is: Do you have googles permission?

Comment: i guess this would me more a technical question, i know there's a legality question...

Comment: not sure if i need permission, im not manipulating the api itself just  referencing it to display the imagemap within a second image... but let me research the legality a bit, thaks

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer...
$mapImage->readImage("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=size:small|{$latitude},{$longitude}&size=160x100&sensor=false");

i guess technically it is possible, but google may have limits on its use